# Prism MVVM: 'No parameterless constructor defined for type' Error when binding ViewModel to View

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, mvvm, prism

I am creating a simple WPF application which has a single view and view model which uses dependency injection in the view model for services which perform calculations.

`App.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
   protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
   {
      IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
      container.RegisterType<ICharacterCountService, CharacterCountService>();
      container.RegisterType<IMathService, MathService>();
      container.RegisterType<IMainWindowViewModel, MainWindowViewModel>();
      ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<MainWindow, MainWindowViewModel>();
      MainWindow mainWindow = container.Resolve<MainWindow>();
      mainWindow.Show();
   }
}
```

`MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="MyFirstMVVM.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyFirstMVVM"
           xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="400"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
```

The constructor in `MainWindowViewModel`:

```
public MainWindowViewModel(IMathService mathService, ICharacterCountService characterCountService)
{
   _mathService = mathService;
   _characterCountService = characterCountService;

   AddCommand = new DelegateCommand(Add);
   CountCommand = new DelegateCommand(Count);
}
```

It appears you can only use the `ViewModelLocator` if you have a paramaterless constructor in the view model, in which case I wouldn't be able to inject `CharacterCountService` and `MathService`. Would I have to use an alternative way of setting the views `DataContext` to the view model?

I have also tried setting the `DataContext` directly in the view, but I get a similar error: [image: XAML error, no parameterless constructor.]

Comment: The provider is not using the container and thus know not how to resolve the dependencies. the provider needs a factory to know how to resolve dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are building a Prism application, your `App` class should derive from `PrismApplication`. It sets up all the infrastructure needed by Prism, also the `ViewModelLocator` that you use. It will automatically wire the current container to the `ViewModelLocationProvider` to resolve types. That means, any constructor with parameters that was registered to the container would work without any further ado.

However, by default, without any initialization, the `ViewModelLocationProvider` will use the [`Activator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator?view=net-5.0) from the reflection namespace to instantiate types like below, which ulimately [requires a parameterless constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=net-5.0#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_).

```
type => Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Consequently, you have two options to make it work.

- Derive your main application type `App` from `PrismApplication` and initialize it properly. To get started, take a look a [*Override the Existing Application Object*](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/wpf/getting-started.html#override-the-existing-application-object)
- Initialize the `ViewModelLocationProvider` type factory yourself.

  ```
  ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory((view, type) => container.Resolve(type));
  ```

As for the XAML declaration, that is exactly the same as instantiating a type in code with a parameterless constructor. Since you do not provide one, you get exactly this error.

```
var mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();
```

Comment: Worth noting: there's one `PrismApplication` for each of the supported containers

Comment: "Derive your main application type App from PrismApplication and initialize it properly. To get started, take a look a Override the Existing Application Object"

This Resolved the issue for me, Thank You! :)